# get String from another Class is passing null

Tags: java, string

I am really wondering why I am not able to pass a String from one class to another as it is Passing null. Here Is My Structure:

```
public class A {

    String myString;

    public A(){
    }

    public String getMyString(){
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString){
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public void doSomethin(){
        String testString = "TEST";
        setMyString(testString);
    }

}
```

And Here is My Class B Structure:

```
public class B {

    A myclassA;

    public B(){
        myClassA = new A();
        createPieModel(myClassA.getMyString());
    }

    public void createPieModel(String branch){
        System.out.println(branch); //getting null at this Point
    }

}
```

Why Am I getting null at createPie Model and what is the Way Around this?

Comment: Do a proper indentation

Comment: What you expect string should be... Where you are setting value to string...

Comment: Because you are not doingSomething...

Comment: Think in `objects`, not in `classes`. I can't see where you call `doSomethin()` or `setMyString()`.

Comment: you dint call doSomethin method in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you never set the value of the String, call the `doSomethin()` method before using the get method

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it in both ways.

```
 public class B{
      A myclassA;
      public B(){
         myClassA = new A();
         myClassA.setMyString("YOUR_MISSED_STRING"); // MISSED_STRING! :)
         createPieModel(myClassA.getMyString());
      }
      public void createPieModel(String branch){
        System.out.println(branch);//getting null at this Point
      }
    }
```

or

```
   public class B{
      A myclassA;
      public B(){
         myClassA = new A();
         myClassA.doSomething(); // missed invokation :)
         createPieModel(myClassA.getMyString());
      }
      public void createPieModel(String branch){
        System.out.println(branch);//getting null at this Point
      }
    }
```